# How to add a js function to ONSEN page load? (monaca)

Tags: javascript, function, templates

I would like an animation to autostart on page load. I'm in the Onsen UI V2 JS Splitter example within the ons-template in an ons-page.

I found that adding a script tag between the "/ons-page" and the "/ons-template" tags gets read (this took me quite some time... (-; )

I followed the [guide](https://onsen.io/v2/docs/js/page.html)

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("init", function(event) {
  if (event.target.id == "score.html") {
    Progress1();
  }
}, false);
</script>
```

But nothing happened.

I changed it to:

.... html stuff

```
    </ons-page>
    <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {Progress1()});
    </script>
  </ons-template>
```

But now it cannot find a component from the HTML file and it says

```
Uncaught Error: container does noet exist #container1 www/lib/jquery-3.1.0.slim.min.js:2
```

What can i do? I solved it now with a button. That proves it works, but is of course no auto start.

Any ideas...?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't look a good way to achieve your goal. You should use [Cordova Events](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html) or, if you need to wait for Onsen to be loaded, `ons.ready` function. Here is an example:

```js
<script>
  ons.ready(function() {
    //execute your code
  });
</script>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Unfortunately it doesn't help, i get the same Uncaught Error. The same function call from the button, on the same page works fine... (it's a mystery).

Comment: It's probably because the element was not loaded yet. `ons.ready` may not work if the element you are trying to access is not an onsen element.

Comment: I see! Thanks Andi. But then, why does $(document).ready(function() {Progress1()});  not work...? Or better asked: how can i make it work..?

Comment: `$( document ).ready()` will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. This doesn't mean that the element you are trying to access has been rendered in the DOM. You can try to wrap your code in a `timeout()` with 3000ms and check if it works. If yes, it's definitely a timing issue.

Comment: It works! Just like that!!!  Thank you! Fantastic!! Is it advisable to leave the timeout() in the code, or is that just to debug?

Comment: Edit: it works on the first page load. If i visit the page again it does not work anymore

Comment: Edit: it stopped working and the error is back. How is this even possible with the same code...? I

Comment: I know why it's not working but it's related to your app navigation logic, I suggest to open a topic on the Onsen UI Forum as the solution will require a lot of discussion

Comment: Ok thanks Maybe i should forget about ons.ready and add it to a page init event...

Comment: ons.ready will be triggered only the first time you'll open the app, not when you go back to the main page

Answer (score 1):

I see this one is old, but anyway.
Onsen UI documentation says:
There are several events you can listen to. 'init' or 'show' will do the trick. Make sure you load the script as an external file, not inline script. Cordova templates are  added and removed on navigation. Inline script is not efficient at all

```html
document.addEventListener('init', function(event) {
  if (event.target.matches('#yourpage')) {
    ons.notification.alert('Page is initiated.');
      // Set up content...
      }        
  }, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

With a lot of help, this is a solution that works. It is an interval that checks if the container 'exists'. It repeats until the container is there and then it calls the function. In the function the interval is cleared (so it stops checking).

See also here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

```
var tryForContainer;

function progression1Test(){
    tryForContainer = setInterval(checkIfContainerIsReady, 100);
}

function checkIfContainerIsReady(){
    //alert(document.getElementById('container1'));
    if(document.getElementById('container1') !== null){
        Progress1();
    }
}
```